# Save photo only if not blurry (Laplacian >200)?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking to save/write photos that are not blurry. How would one go about combining the two codes below?

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('./facesData/ID.jpg')
cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 8)
    for x,y,w,h in faces:

        sampleN = sampleN + 1
        cv2.imwrite("./facesData/ID." + str(sampleN) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        cv2.waitKey(2)

    cv2.imshow('user', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    if sampleN > 20:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'd suggest improving your question description. The question title is clear but the description does not clearly describe, the task you are trying to achieve and the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moves your blurry images into a separate folder ([code source](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)).

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
import os
from pathlib import Path

#%% Setup paths
script_dir = str(Path(__file__).parents[0]) # path this script is running in
source_images_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'images')

#%%
def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

#%% loop over the input images
threshold = 200

for file_name in os.listdir(source_images_dir):
    image_path = os.path.join(source_images_dir, file_name)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path) # load the image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
    fm = variance_of_laplacian(image) # calculate blur
    text = "Not Blurry"

    # if the focus measure is less than the supplied threshold,
    # then the image should be considered "blurry"
    if fm >= threshold:
        text = "Blurry"

    #%% Once ready to move clear images, uncomment this section
    else:
        focused_images_path = os.path.join(script_dir,
                                           'blurry_images',
                                           file_name)
        os.rename(image_path, focused_images_path)

    #%% Comment out the following section when ready to batch move your images
    cv2.putText(image, "{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm), (10, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image) # Press ENTER to cycle through images
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

To use it setup your folder structure like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
    count = count+1;
    face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    file_name_path = './facesData/ID.' +str(id)+ '.' +str(count)+ '.' + '.jpg'
    if cv2.Laplacian(face, cv2.CV_64F).var() >500:
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

    else:
        count -= 1

     cv2.imshow('user', frame)

else:
    pass

if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or count == 20
```